# Why does let require a vector?

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp, let

I never really thought about this until I was explaining some clojure code to a coworker who wasn't familiar with clojure.  I was explaining `let` to him when he asked why you use a vector to declare the bindings rather than a list.  I didn't really have an answer for him.  But the language *does* restrict you from using lists:

```
=> (let (x 1) x)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: let requires a vector for its binding (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Why exactly is this?

Comment: I imagine it's purely for readability, and having let enforce a vector simply ensures the idiom is kept.

Comment: (A literal vector is required for pretty much all "let" and "with-" macros.)

Comment: This is kind like natural laws. You can reason *that* it is like that, but not *why*. Whether the real reason for this decision was readability, some Scheme implementation, a convention or the type of breakfast Rich had at that day remains in the dark. The only one who can answer this is Rich himself. For Clojure we are in a lucky position, for the universe....

Comment: A related thread comparing "Clojure vs Common Lisp let" provides some "official" quotes and slide from Rich : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365000/clojure-let-vs-common-lisp-let

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mostly readability, I imagine. Whenever bindings are needed in Clojure, a vector is pretty consistently used. A lot of people agree that vectors for bindings make things flow better, and make it easier to discern what the bindings are and what the running code is.

Just for fun:

```
user=> (defmacro list-let [bindings & body] `(let ~(vec bindings) ~@body))
#'user/list-let
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(list-let (x 0) (println x)))
(clojure.core/let [x 0] (println x))
user=> (list-let (x 0 y 1) (println x y))
0 1
nil
```

Comment: I vote for this answer, since it beat mine by 2 minutes **AND** has code!  Good show!

Comment: True, Hickey mentioned readability reason in his ... concurrency talk, I think it was.

Comment: Using a literal vector also makes it clear it isn't a function call. list-let works but you have to know that first list isn't evaluated normally. Once you have literal vector syntax you might as well take advantage of it.

Comment: I tend to write [~@bindings] when needed in my macros instead of ~(vec binding). I found it easier to read.

Comment: Hamish: His concurrency talk?  When's the last time Rich talked about something that did not involve concurrency?  :-)

Answer (score 13):

This is an idiom from Scheme. In many Scheme implementations, square brackets can be used interchangeably with round parentheses in list literals. In those Scheme implementations, square brackets are often used to distinguish parameter lists, argument lists and bindings from S-expressions or data lists.

In Clojure, parentheses and brackets mean different things, but they are used the same way in binding declarations.

Answer (score 11):

Clojure tries very hard to be consistent.  There is no technical reason with a list form could not have been used in `let`, `fn`, `with-open`, etc...  In fact, you can create your own `my-let` easily enough that uses one instead.  However, aside from standing out visibly, the vector is used consistently across forms to mean "here are some bindings".  You should strive to uphold that ideal in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that it's *a convention*

`fn` used it, `defn` used it, `loop` uses.

it seems that it's for everything that resembles a block of code that has some parameters; more specific, the square brackets are for marking those parameters

other forms for blocks of code don't use it, like `if` or `do`. they don't have any parameters

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about this is that `let` is simply derived from lambda. These two expressions are equivalent:

```
((fn [y] (+ y 42)) 10)
(let [y 10] (+ 42 y))
```

So as an academic or instructional point, you could even write your own very rudimentary version of `let` that took a list as well as a vector:

```
(defmacro my-let [x body]
  (list (list `fn[(first x)]
              `~body)
        (last x)))

(my-let (z 42) (* z z))
```

although there would be no practical reason to do this.